# Drupal Breadcrumbs and modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-routes

I have created a module but the page structure is not picked up by the breadcrumb so I would expect this to be

home > personal > contact form

and what I get is

home > contact form

it is like the structure is ignore, what do I need to do to get this picked up by the breadcrumbs?

```
$items['personal/contact-form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Contact Us',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('contactform_enquiries'),
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would only work if you had a menu item at `/personal' as well. I would just set the breadcrumb manually in your form callback:

```
function contactform_enquiries($form, &$form_state) {
  $breadcrumb = array(
    l('Home', '<front>'),
    l('Personal', 'personal'),
    'Contact Form'
  );

  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
}
```